# How do I cut an FLV video into several small pieces?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to cut an FLV video to several small FLV videos with FFmpeg through PHP.

The small videos may have the same length.

Comment: This isn't really a PHP issue, but an FFmpeg one, thus off topic here.

Comment: You could of course simply call `ffmpeg` multiple times with different cut parameters (see `-ss` and `-t`) options and script that through PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 
    ffmpeg command

and execute it using

```
exec
```

function in php

for reference check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139248/to-cut-flv-video-using-php)

Comment: i know ffmpeg can cut a piece video from a long one, but what i want is to cut the long video into several parts once.As i know ffmpeg can only cut one part once.Do you know any other methods?  thank you for your answer