# Function to download specific part of video in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to download specific part of video. I have download button. when someone click on download button I want to download the video after cutting video by 20 sec.

This is my view code.

```
<a href="/download" style="background:red; color:white; padding:12px "> download</a>
```

This is my route function where I am downloading video.

```
Route:: get('/download',function(){

      $file=public_path().'/Untitled 1.mp4';

     $header=array('Content-Type:application/video',
      );


     return Response::download($file,"Untitled 1.mp4",$header);

       });
```

I want to download video after cutting video by 20 sec.

Comment: First, you need to implement the video cut software in backend :) Use https://madewithlaravel.com/laravel-ffmpeg or something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139248/to-cut-flv-video-using-php

Comment: so first u mean to download and install ffmpeg in my system

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to solve the mysterious problem on your own?

Comment: @Waled I did not use it but looks like a PHP repo - you can get it via composer `pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg` - https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg (LE: I wrote "in back-end" because I saw the HTML and thought maybe you have a JavaScript interface... now I saw it's the same route, my bad)